# which dll necessary for upload in host?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When i publish my project in visual studio, which dll necessary for upload in host?**

in asp.core 2.2  only create 6 file in my publish file,but when migrate to asp.core 3.1 i have this problem

[image]

Comment: If that's the output of your publish, then just push them to the host. They're not *that* big

Comment: but the same project in asp core 2.2 i only had 9 dll in my publish folder?!!!

Comment: The package you're using might be moved from the framework to Nuget, hence showing up on publish output, and/or you've simply changed the publishing option.

Comment: Can I delete any of them?

Answer (score 1):

On .NET Core 3.0, some assemblies are [moved out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-package-references-for-removed-assemblies) from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`, including EF Core and Identity UI.

Comment: Can I delete any of them?

Comment: No. They're copied out to publishing folder because they *are* needed.